# Inter Portlet Communication in JetSpeed2

Tags: portlet, jetspeed2

I am looking for code to do inter portlet communication in JetSpeed Client Side. I tried browsing around but there is no correct wikis available. I know a way of using bind and fire functions of JQuery which still have to check. Also wanted to know if there is any API inside Jetspeed for the same?

Comment: I am looking to do IPC on server side. Does anyone have a link for the same? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this point you in the right direction?
http://portalstepbystep.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/inter-portlet-communication-overview.html